# How to make TestNG wait for my test to complete before shutting it down

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

I have a slightly complicated test structure so bear with me,

I have a series of testng test cases and during each I collect some data about the test( not directly but using a library which I wrote). This library once it gets the data kicks off an analysis program on another thread and the main thread proceeds with executing the rest of the test. (I do this because the analysis is slightly time consuming and I don't want the main test to block).

At the end only a few analysis program threads are left but testng still shuts the test down and the data for the last few test cases could not be analysed.

I don't want a hardcoded sleep at the end. Is there a way I can direct TestNG to wait until any threads spawned by this test (directly or via associated libraries) finish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can in general do one of the following:
1) By making the main Thread wait for another Thread using

```
Thread.join();
```

2) Making the another Thread as Non Daemon or a user thread:[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean))

```
Thread.setDaemon(false);
```

The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.This method must be called before the thread is started.